# Converting scientific notation to TeX math mode format

Tags: sed, replace

I have several equations mixed throughout a document, appearing in the following forms:

```
5^4 %A
3^-1 %B
5.01 x 10^2.05 %C
5.01 x 10^2 %D
-5 x 10^3 %E
```

In other words, they fit in the format of `x^y`, or `z * x^y`, where z, x, and y can be any integer or rational number (expressed with a decimal point), positive or negative.

I wish to convert these to math mode for TeX. E.g.:

```
$5.01 \cdot 10^2$
```

With much assistance from others, I have managed to create this `BASH` script with `sed` to solve items A and B:

```
sed "s/\-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}^\-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}/$&$/" input > output
```

This is able to convert items A and B to math mode, but I found it only converts the first occurrence it finds within a line. For instance, if a line says `5^10 is greater than 1^2` it converts this to `$5^10$ is greater than 1^2`. A second pass with the script results in `$$5^10$$ is greater than 1^2`.

I managed to modify the above script to handle items C, D, and E, but cannot figure out how to handle the back second part (I have marked it with "???"):

```
sed "s/\-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}\ x\ \-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}^\-\{0,1\}[0-9]\{1,\}/???/" input > output
```

This presents a problem:

- Even if the above could work, if I first run the first `sed` script, then run the second, the first confuses the second, i.e. I would end up with `5.01 x $10^2.05$`. If I ran the second script first, I would end up with `$5.01 x $10^2.05$$` after running the second script.

In short, how can I perform this kind of conversion for all items within a document?

```
5^4 --> $5^4$
3^-1 --> $3^-1$
5.01 x 10^2.05 --> $5.01 \cdot 10^2.05$
5.01 x 10^2 --> $5.01 \cdot 10^2$
-5 x 10^3 --> $-5 \cdot 10^3$
```

Comment: In 5^4 %A do you want %A to be removed post processing?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I have updated the answer. Can you please try it and let me know if it works for you?

Comment: @Village the metacharacters `?` meaning optional i.e. none or 1, `+` meaning one or more and `*` meaning none or more, may make you regex's easier on the eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I found it only converts the first occurrence it finds within a line

Use the [`/g`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6) global replacement flag.

Converting your text is best done in several passes

Pass 1

```
 sed 's/\(-\?[0-9].\?[0-9]*\) x \(-\?[0-9]\{1,\}\)^\([0-9]\{1,\}\.\?[0-9]*\)/$\1 cdot \2^^\3$/g' input > tmp
```

What we've done here is capture `\(...\)` x `\(...\)`^`\(...\)` into the sed remembered patterns `\1` `\2` and `\3` which we then use to convert the text.

This deals with your %C,%D,%E and for example converts `5.01 x 10^2.05` into `$5.01 cdot 10^^2.05$`. Note that we have converted the occurrences of `^` into `^^` temporarily.

Pass 2

```
sed -i 's/-\?[0-9]\+\^-\?[0-9]\+/$&$/g' tmp
```

This deals with your examples %A and %B. As we previously converted the `^` in `10^2.05` to `^^` this was ignored by pass 2 solving the problems you noted.

Pass 3

```
sed -i 's/\^^/^/g' tmp
```

Which simply converts the `^^` back into `^`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you need, will this following method work for you?

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat file0
5^4
3^-1
5.01 x 10^2.05
5.01 x 10^2
-5 x 10^3

[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed -e 's/^/\$/' -e 's/$/\$/' -e 's/x/\\cdot/' file0
$5^4$
$3^-1$
$5.01 \cdot 10^2.05$
$5.01 \cdot 10^2$
$-5 \cdot 10^3$
```

Comment: this may work for the example given but I don't think it would generally.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed -i 's/\(-\?[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\? \)x\( -\?[0-9]\+\^-\?[0-9]\+\(\.[0-9]\+\)\?\)\|\(-\?[0-9]\+\^-\?[0-9]\+\)/$\1\\cdot\3\5$/g;s/\$\\cdot/$/g' file
```

although the `GNU sed` `-r` switch makes it look a lot less cluttered:

```
 sed -ri 's/(-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? )x( -?[0-9]+\^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)|(-?[0-9]+\^-?[0-9]+)/$\1\\cdot\3\5$/g;s/\$\\cdot/$/g' file
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the case of `5^10 is greater than 1^2`.